# User can mention two users. | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a command to ship users on Discord.

I tried making it so two users have to be mentioned, but only one user would work.

How do I make it so you must mention two users?

```js
run: async(bot, message, args) => {
    let user1 = message.mentions.users.first()

    if(!user1) return message.channel.send('I need to ship.')

    let user2 = message.mentions.users.first(args[1])

    if(!user2) return message.channel.send('I need a second user...')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[.first()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) only gets the first [mention](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions)

Answer (score 0):

put -1 in .first() for the bot to understand that it will be the second mention of the message
Example code:
user2 = message.mentions.users.first(-1)

Answer (score 0):

If want to get the user or member object apart from the first one, then you can do:

```
var secondUser = message.mentions.users.first(2)[1]; //second mentioned user.
var thirdUser = message.mentions.users.first(3)[2]; //third mentioned user.
```

and so on. Or you can use `message.mentions.users.array()` to get all mentions as an array, and then you can use the User object from that array.